Copying files and directories using a single method from shutil (copytree is not a solution)
I'm trying to implement this shell expression cp ~/.config/profiles/* $HOME in python with shutil
But I can't find optimal method that would check if file is a directory for me, instead I'm ending up with this code:
for file_path in Path().home().joinpath(".config/profiles").iterdir():
    filename = str(file_path).split("/")[-1]
    destination = Path.home().joinpath(filename)
    if not destination.exists() and file_path.exists():
        copytree(src=file_path, dst=destination) if file_path.is_dir() else copy(src=file_path, dst=destination)

    print(destination, file_path)

I thought that maybe it's the design of shutil, but then I found shutil.move method that basically moves file or directory to the destination.
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

shutil.move(src, dst, copy_function=copy2)¶
Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location and return the destination.

Can you tell how I can copy file or directory to the destination without any conditions, because I couldn't find any related method in shutil
UPDATE:
I wrote copyall function that I expected to find in shutil:
def copyall(src: str, dst: str):
    """Copy all files or/and directories from one directory inside of another directory"""
    if Path(src).is_dir() and Path(dst).is_dir():
        for file_path in Path(src).iterdir():
            if file_path.is_dir():
                copytree(file_path, Path(dst) / file_path.name)
            else:
                copy(file_path, Path(dst) / file_path.name)


What do you mean without any conditions? Is it alright if we check the filename is a directory or path and then run a command based on that result?

@SharpDev It isn't what I want, you don't check file when use shutil.move. While with copy you need to clarify the type of the file first, and then decide whether you use shutil.copytree or shutil.copy.

@SharpDev I'm looking for simple one line solution like shutil.move but for copy

There's no method in shutil that will move files and/or directories at the same time without the condition... What you can do is you could make a directory. Then you could move whatever you are copying into that directory copy the directory to the destination then perform 2 more moves to move the files/directory out of the directory you just created and do the same in the destination... But that's way less efficient I think... You could use a lower level package, but you'll have to pay attention to the differences between linux and windows systems.

@SharpDev I just don't understand why they didn't create the similar method like shutil.move but for copy, there's gotta be a reason. Right? Overall python isn't a low level language where you need to implement such a functionality by yourself, this method should be there by default.
